# c - O_TRUNC and O_APPEND for system call open()

Tags: c, system-calls

The access mode bits `O_TRUNC` and `O_APPEND` are for system call `open()`'s 2nd parameter.

They shouldn't be used together, I guess, because they conflict, or 1 will override another, I think.

But I saw following in `<The linux programming interface>` page 73, is that a bad way?

```
d = open("w.log", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_APPEND,S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
```

Comment: Where have you seen that they shouldn't be used together ? They can. TRUNC and APPEND do different things and don't interfere.

Comment: @chmike If the original file is truncated first, then how can you still append to it? Or, they have other meaning?

Comment: append simply means that all writes will be at the end.  If append is not set, a process can write data and later overwrite it  (or, more importantly, overwrite data that another process is writing concurrently).  if append is set, such overwrites are not possible.

Comment: @Eric Wang You'll append to the truncated file. ;)

Comment: @chmike seems to me it is the same as specify `O_TRUNC` without `O_APPEND`

Comment: It looks the same in term of data written to the file. But it's not in practice. When the file is opened with append mode, writes are faster. I've seen it with benchamrks. I also saw a ptrace showing the difference. The system calls are different.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Now I understand the important role that `O_APPEND` play to provide atomic operation, via write a program for TLPI exercise 5.3.